# send Dropdownlist index as a parameter to WS thru Javascript, How?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to send 2 parameters to my WS with Jquery Autocomplete:

1. textbox, where i want complete
2. dropdownlist index

i have a problem to get the dropdownlist index, as i get only the name of the Controller.

this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#<%= TextBoxes1.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WB/EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmpolyeeId",
                    data: "{ 'Text': '" + request.term + "','SelectedIndex':'" + '#<%= DP1.ClientID %>' + "'}",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);

                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 0
        });

    });

</script>
```

and this is my WS :

```
public List<string> GetEmpolyeeId(string Text, string SelectedIndex)
```

what i need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it!!! :-)

this is what i done:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=DP1.ClientID%>');
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= TextBoxes1.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WB/EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails",
                    data: "{ 'Text': '" + request.term + "','SelectedIndex':'" + ddl.selectedIndex  <%--'#<%= DP1.ClientID %>'--%> + "'}",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 0
        });

    });
</script>
```

i added a variable to "data" (the Dropdownlist index), while i defined the Dropdownlist before entering the function.

the WS styed the same.

Comment: i cannot put V on my answer, because i don't have the permissions. if someone will do it, i will appreciate it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need following 2 , as you had mentioned in question.

1. textbox, where i want complete -- `request.term` , you are using it correctly.
2. dropdownlist index -- assuming dropdownlist id is `DP1`, you need to get its index using following

`$("#<%= DP1.ClientID %>")[0].selectedIndex`

So putting all things in one line, it will be,

`data: "{ 'Text': '" + request.term + "','SelectedIndex':'" + $("#<%= DP1.ClientID %>")[0].selectedIndex + "'}",`

**Example**

```js
function OnChangeVal() {
  alert($("#sel")[0].selectedIndex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="OnChangeVal()" id="sel">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```